# Disable global ASUS GameVisual Hotkeys on ASUS TUF Gaming A15

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, asus-laptop, bloatware

I have an ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506IV with preinstalled ASUS Services, most notably the App Armoury Crate. This App includes the GameVisual feature for changing display settings to predetermined profiles.

There is a global Hotkey combination of Fn+v which changes the profile setting and thus messes with my display settings.
I constantly hit this accidentially, because I have another laptop that has a ctrl. key at the position of the function key (ctrl+v is in the muscle memory).

I haven't found a way to disable this hotkey combination other than stopping all the Armoury Crate background processes, and this is not really an option because once these processes are stopped the only way to make Armoury Crate work again is restarting the computer, and i'd like to keep access to some other features of this app.

It seems, that since all of this came preinstalled, I'm also not able to uninstall just the GameVisual part of the app (At least I can't find it in the list of installed apps)

Also, I don't want to disable the Fn key entirely. It's just this one combination that's annoying the heck out of me.

On a side note, if someone knows how to get access to fan control  and keyboard lighting on my hardware without the whole Armoury Crate ASUS bloatware, i'll happily just uninstall all of it.

But my main question is: Is there a way to disable just this one hotkey combination?

EDIT:
Because of a comment request:
[List of ASUS Programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNjA.png)

Comment: It absolutely is possible to uninstall the ASUS software you describe.  When you view your installed programs, can you provide a screenshot showing a filtered results of your installed program, that contain the word "ASUS"?

Comment: @Ramhound i posted the requested screenshot. There is no program "GameVisuals" in my list of installed programs either (i think it only appears as standalone program if it doesn't come preinstalled and you download it from the store)

Comment: You could always submit this question to the forums on ASUS, I was able to solve my one and only problem with my own ASUS motherboard, by looking to that forum for assistance.

Comment: Yes, I will probably try that. Thank you for your help anyways!

Answer (score 2):

> But my main question is: Is there a way to disable just this one hotkey combination?

Based on what I can tell, if there isn't an explicit option to change the shortcut key, it won't be possible to change or disable the hotkey itself.

> On a side note, if someone knows how to get access to fan control and keyboard lighting on my hardware without the whole Armoury Crate ASUS bloatware, i'll happily just uninstall all of it.

I believe you will find, the software does not allow you to configure the shortcut keys, and you will be forced to uninstall Armoury Crate.  Armoury Crate can easily be uninstalled.

ASUS has a mobile application that allows you to control your RGB through WiFi/BlueTooth

> 1. Click the link to go to the [Armoury Crate support](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/Armoury%20Crate/HelpDesk_Download/) website
> 2. Find the `Driver & Utility` tab and select the OS as `Windows 10 64-bit` to download `Armoury Crate Uninstall Tool`
> 3. Unzip `Armoury_Crate_Uninstall_Tool.zip` and double-click `Armoury Crate Uninstall Tool.exe` to start the uninstall process.
> 4. Select to install a single App (Armoury Crate or AURA Creator), or to install both. Click the “Start” button to run the installation
>    process.
>
> [image]

Source: [1-1-4. Using Armoury Crate to configure peripherals on non-compatible devices](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1041654/#1-2.%20How%20to%20uninstall%20Armoury%20Crate)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not really willing to loose my already limited control over my fans. I haven't even been able to find an app that's able to display my fan speed, so i depend on Armoury Crate for that. Also, I read that reinstalling Armoury Crate can be tedious...

Comment: Based on the documentation it doesn't appear to be tedious.

Comment: So your suggestion is to uninstall Armoury Crate and then reinstall it after? How is that going to help?

Comment: @GWD - **My actual answer is that it's not possible to change or disable the keyboard shortcut in question.**  So the only solution, in order to disable the keyboard shortcut, is to actually uninstall the software.  You should be able to control your keyboard lighting through `AURA Creator` if you keep it installed.  Additionally, you should be able to control your fans and RGB lighting, through the mobile application ASUS provides.